# C# double型の計算について

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

```
double d = 344.328;
d *= 10000;
```

こういったことをしているのですが、通常なら3443280になるところが、何度実行しても
344327.9999.....といった数になってしまうのですが、これはどうしてなのでしょうか。

原因と対策を教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

浮動小数点数は正確な小数表現ではありません。

```
double d = 344.328;
```

は`344.328`を`double`で表せる最も近い値として扱われます。そのため最小限の誤差があります。その上で

```
d *= 10000;
```

により誤差が10000倍に拡大します。その結果、質問のような状況が発生します。
正確な小数表現で演算したい場合は`decimal`を使用します。

Comment: ありがとうございました。いつも助けていただいてすみません。decimalを使用したら直りました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたしますm(_ _)m